# get url login password from BasicDatasource bean spring

Tags: java, spring, datasource

i need to get url/login and password from this bean:

`appcontext.getBean("dataSource");`

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/webDatasource"/> 
</bean>
```

Jndi was configured under weblogic

If i put a breakpoint in my application, i can see login/url/password int the variable view.

But there is no getter on those parameters.

How can i get those informations? another method/bean can do this?

Today, the solution is to put all this informations into the database, but if i can do it more simply, because if the login or the url change, i don't need to update the DB.

thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you need the username/password from that datasource? Also, how are you creating the datasource?

Comment: i need to call an extern script via ProcessBuilder and this script need to create a connection ;)

Comment: I see. How is the datasource getting created?

Comment: its was created by spring, and used a jndi datasource declared in weblogic   like : <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/webDatasource"/>
    </bean>

Comment: I propose that you obtain the DataSource from the script via JNDI if possible

Comment: no its not possible, thats why i ask here to see if its possible to do that in my webapp ;) because i don t want (if its possible) to put this information in my datasource...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60501/discussion-between-mancaux-pierre-alexandre-and-geoand).